# return type of generic methods

Tags: java, generics

If I have a method, for instance

```
public INode getNode(final int offset);
```

I assume it doesn't add something to make the method return type generic, for instance:

```
public <T extends INode> T getNode(final int offset);
```

Or did I miss something? I think generic return types are only of value if one of the parameters is of the same type (or a super/subtype)?

Comment: It's possible that it adds more value, however, I would think that it would add even more value if the generic parameter was defined in the class.

Comment: What is the question? What "doesn't add something" means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> public <T extends INode> T getNode(final int offset);
> ```

Not only does this not provide any additional information to the caller, but is outright dangerous: The only way to implement that method signature is to use an *unchecked cast*, which can not be type safe, because a method's type parameters are specified by its caller (explicitly or implictly through type inference), and the type parameters aren't  available to this method's implementation. For instance, consider the following program:

```
class NodeCollection {
    private INode[] nodes = new INode[42];

    public <T extends INode> T getNode(final int offset) {
        return (T) nodes[offset];
    }

    public <T extends INode> setNode(final int offset, T node) {
        nodes[offset] = node;
    }
}

class ANode implements INode {}
class BNode implements INode {
    void foo();
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NodeCollection nc = new NodeCollection();
        nc.setNode(0,new ANode());
        BNode b = nc.getNode(0); // throws ClassCastException (sic!)
    }
}
```

Best practice: Don't use an unchecked cast, unless you are *really* sure it'll be type correct at runtime.

> I think generic return types are only of value if one of the parameters is of the same type (or a super/subtype)?

There are more cases, for instance:

```
public <T> T getFavorite(Class<T> clazz) {
    return clazz.cast(favorites.get(clazz));
}
```

or

```
interface List<E> {
    E get(int index);
}
```

or the examples in Colin's answer, where the type variable merely appears *as type parameter* in the return type, which is acceptable due to type erasure.

**Edit**:

> I think there's no type save way if one wants to cast to the exact type of node (instead of instanceof has to precede it)

Of course there is, it's called [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: We are persisting nodes as INodes, that is of the interface INode as every node has to implement it. Then we have an interface IStructNode for "structural" nodes. A transaction cursor provides the above method, for instance moveTo(nodeID) whereas it internally invokes getNode(offset). Another method is getNode() which delivers nodes as INodes, and getStructuralNode() as IStructNode or wrapped in a "NullNode" which implements the null object pattern. I think there's no type save way if one wants to cast to the exact type of node (instead of instanceof has to precede it)

Comment: Was this supposed to amend your question? If so, then please use the question's edit button. That would also allow you to structure and format the amendement.

Comment: Yes, for sure, the visitor pattern ;-) I've implemented it about a year ago, but just didn't thought about it... ah well.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you give, it doesn't really add any value except forcing the developer of the implementation to cast the return value (in `T`). (Unless it has a way to get a `T` value, but for that it would need to call another method which returns `T`, so you're just moving the cast a bit further.

So not really a good idea in the case you're showing us.

---

There are a few cases where the generic applied only to the return value can be useful. For example:

```
public static <T> Collection<T> generateCollection() {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

This allows you to create an object `Collection` of `T` without having to do any cast.

Or if you want the developer doing the implementation to cast his object (mostly works when the said object uses generics), example from `Collections`:

```
public static final <T> Set<T> emptySet() {
    return (Set<T>) EMPTY_SET;
}
```

---

**Resources:**

- [angelikalanger.com: Java Generics FAQs - Generic Methods](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedMethods.html)